# Adding second relay coil in parallel with the first one creates buzzing in the first

Tags: relay, grounding, buzzing

In my cargo trailer/camper conversion, I used a DPDP 120 VAC coil relay (JQX-62F-2X 80 Amp) to connect the breaker panel to shore power or to an inverter (for battery power source). The coil is connected to the shore power source wiring so the inverter gets connected automatically when shore power is absent. The two poles carry hot and neutral.
I had trouble in a few campgrounds with my system kicking out the GFCI outlets on the RV shore power post. Traced that down to trouble with all my grounds in the RV being common. So I wanted to add a second relay to switch the ground circuits along with the hot and neutrals. I added a HF 105F-4 SPDT relay with its 120 VAC coil in parallel with the other relay. That makes the first relay buzz rather loudly. Need to stop that.
I have tried exchanging the leads on the HF 105F to make the current flow in the opposite direction in that coil, and also tried disconnecting (separating) all the ground circuits. Neither worked.
A total mystery to me but must be some interaction going on between the two coils. I am guessing a capacitor or diode maybe? Have no idea where to add them though. (The relays can be found on Amazon.)[image: Electrical Schematic Diagram]

Comment: Please update your qrestion with a circuit diagram.

Comment: You *"Traced that down to trouble with all my grounds in the RV being common."* What exactly was the root cause that you determined caused the *"system kicking out the GFCI outlets on the RV shore power post"*? In detail, I mean -- can you explain how \$4\:\text{mA} \to 6\:\text{mA}\$ (per UL 943) was exceeded?

Comment: I had the ground lug of the inverter, the ground circuit of the shore power, the vehicle ground (trailer chassis) all tied to one another. In some camp grounds I had no problem, in others I had to disconnect the inverter to avoid the GFCI on the power post kicking off my power.
Sorry, I am not conversant with UL 943 (or any other such spec. I'm a Physics major - which makes me dangerous. : )

Comment: @RussellH Schematic posted in original question.

Comment: Not hearing any ideas, I keep chewing on it myself. The relay must be seeing some kind of oscillation or it wouldn't buzz just because a second relay is adding (coils in parallel with one another) so that oscillation needs to be damped. Because these are 120 VAC coils, a diode isn't going to work so I am thinking a capacitor? (The buzzing is not the relay contacts jumping up and down - well, I don't think so anyway.) Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, mystery solved! I had a spare HF 105F-4 SPDT relay so I tried it and the buzzing of the other relay was absent. Something strange with the first HF 105F-4 SPDT.